# Input Sources Menu not working

Tags: macos

I recently updated to Sierra.  Now the Input Sources Menu isn't working.  My 2 source are listed (US & Unicode) but selecting them does nothing.  The checkmark doesn't move, the menu title doesn't change, and the keyboard function doesn't change.

Additionally, the "Show/Hide input source name", "Show Emoji & symbols", and "Show character viewer" menu options tend to just disappear from the menu and stay gone until reboot.

Any idea what would cause this, and/or how to fix?

Comment: Try setting up another user account and see if you have the same problem when logged into that.

Comment: @TomGewecke Logging into the Guest Account, it works fine.  Does that suggest it's a bad prefs file?  And if so, which one covers this stuff?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* I have fixed it.  Based on some pages I found, I ended up deleting some prefs:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.HIToolbox*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox*
```

After rebooting, the menu now acts normally.  If no other problems crop up soon, I'll mark this as answered.